# Force a refresh/reload of the page when the user navigates "back"

Tags: html, refresh

You know how when you're in some type of online banking and you press back and you get a white screen with the  text saying you have to do a resubmit on the page to do a complete refresh? I want to do that in one of my applications. How does one  do it? I've tried the following meta tags, but it's not working:

```
<meta http-equiv=expires content=-1>
<meta http-equiv=Cache-Control CONTENT=no-cache>
<meta http-equiv=Pragma CONTENT=no-cache>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's name the page that you want to refresh "MainPage".

Let's say the user goes from page A to MainPage *through a `<form/>` submission*, then go to page B. If the user goes back to MainPage, the "resubmit" popup will appear. Otherwise, the browser will get the page from the cache.

Now, adding the "meta" tags that you list should force the browser to refresh the page and not load it from the cache. But the "resubmit popup" only appears when the user goes to a page that was generated through `<form/>` submission.

Answer (score 0):

I think that theyt have some page in between. So a page does a header redirect, if the user comes from a specific page but shows a message, if the user pressed back on the target page.

Answer (score 0):

The white screen you're describing is due to an HTTP form POST between pages, not just a straight forward link. The browser is asking whether you want to re-post the entire request. So you could use a `<form>` tag with `method="post"`.